# DDD design comunication beetween aggregates

Tags: domain-driven-design

I wanted to model domain of simple game.

We have a player which can buy different buildings, he have also a stock, and player can have other things which I'm going to add in the future. But for now I'm focusing only on buildings and stock.

I decided to divide it into three aggregates roots Player, PlayerBuildingManagment, PlayerStock. Im not sure if it is proper division, because  Stock, and PlayerBuildingManagment are very related to Player so mayby it shouldn't be aggregate roots. On the other hand I don't want to create one huge aggregate. In my case concurrency will not be a problem because everything stock, building managment will be modified only by one player.

Player

Stock
1. AddToStock()
2. TakeFromStock()

PlayerBuildingManagment
1. AddBuilding()

Now I need to implement process where player will buy a building so I need to

1. Check if he have enough resources and take it from a stock Stock.TakeFromStock()
2. I need to add building PlayerBuildingManagment.AddBuilding().
3. Persist data.

I can realize this process inside one service function but from what I know we shouldn't modify state of two aggregates inside one transaction. What do you think how this communication should be realized.
Maybe I should implement stock and buildingmanagment inside player aggregate. Or create some process manager to make this communication. Could you please give me some clue.

Comment: For single-threaded processes where there is no contention I guess it doesn't really matter what your boundaries are. The rule not to modify multiple aggregates in a single transaction is to reduce the number of transactionnal failures, which you do not have here. Also, you do not even need any locking mechanism because there is no possible race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining transactional consistency between aggregates, which, by definition, are their own consistency boundaries, is problematic to say the least.

Let's go with your notion that there are Players, PlayerStock -- which acts like a bank, and PlayerBuildingManager -- which acts like a contractor.

Regarding the problem of checking for sufficient stock and the request to build building Y by player P for cost X, I'd probably send the PlayerStock aggregate a single command that takes these parameters:

- the player id, P,
- the amount of stock to take, X, and,
- what to do if the stock take is successful:

Here the caller of this message to PlayerStock, will provide a "what to do" that effectively represents a message to send to someone else on success (you might also have a "what to do" on failure, but that is another matter).

In this case, "what to do" message parameter would encode a command to build a building, Y, for player X, and that is to be sent to PlayerBuildingManager.

The rest can be handled with eventual consistency that is typical of multiple aggregates.

Thus, some controller via the UI sends PlayerStock a message to deduct some amount X from player P and to send some message on success.  On success, it will execute the success message, which is a message to PlayerBuildingManager to construct building Y for player P.  There will be an eventual consistency period for which stock has been deducted but the building has not yet materialized.  That is the eventual consistency you buy into when using multiple aggregates.

The reason to encode the on-success message as a parameter is so that you can more loosely couple PlayerStock from the catalog of things that can be constructed and by who can construct them.  An arbitrary on-success message as a parameter will provide a high degree of flexibility without PlayerStock having to know too much.

(If you don't want to deal with that you can put them all in the same aggregate, of course.)

---

If you want to go further:

Let's say the PlayerBuildingManager fails at building the building in the command it received from the PlayerStock.  Well, it should return the stock.  But to keep things loosely coupled, the PlayerStock can provide a message to send in that case, which returns X to PlayerStock for P.

Also you might consider what happens if construction of the building takes not just latency but real-time (as would be the case in the real world).  In that case, the player may want to cancel construction, and may or may not be allowed to do so, and maybe with full refund or partial refund...

Comment: What you describes seems best handled by a process manager a.k.a Saga.